# delete files older than X minutes

Tags: shell, perl

I want to move files and Directories older than 15 min of creation to archive folder in HP Unix but i did not find any option for it. I created a Perl script for it but it is moving files only not directories.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use File::Copy;
my $dstdir = '/tmp/test14';
@ARGV = ("/tmp/test11/") unless @ARGV;
print STDERR "Begin @ ", scalar localtime, "\n";
find(
    sub {
        if ( -f $_ && -M _ >= 1/96 ) {
            print STDERR "Moving '$_'\n";
            move( $File::Find::name, $dstdir ) or die "$!\n";
        }
    },
    @ARGV );
print STDERR "Ended @ ", scalar localtime, "\n";
1;
```

Input:

```
/tmp/test11# ll
drwxrwxrwx   2 root       sys             96 Mar 14 21:46 hello
drwxrwxrwx   2 root       sys             96 Mar 14 21:46 hello1
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root       sys              0 Mar 14 22:03 hello3
```

Output:

```
/tmp/test14# ll
-rw-rw-rw-   1 root       sys              0 Mar 14 22:03 hello3
```

Comment: Are you using [HP Unix's standard `find`](http://ods.com.ua/win/eng/unix/usail/man/hpux/find.1.html) (no `-cmin` option), or do you have access to GNU `find`?

Comment: This is what happens when you copy-paste scripts... The script only moves regular files because that's what the author wanted: `if ( -f $_` ... are you the author ? Then how comes you don't understand what your own script does ?

Comment: Your title says *"delete files older than X minutes"*, but your post says *"I want to move files"*, which is it?

Comment: @haukex - that's a minor detail - you still have to know which ones to move or delete so the operation itself is not that important; what's worse is that OP is using _"creation time"_ when the requirement here seems to be finding files based on _"modification time"_ (at least, that's what OP's script appears to do). Even worse, (based on the comments, answers and upvotes) it looks like people here think `gnu find`'s `cmin n` checks if the file was _created_ n minutes ago.

Comment: @don_crissti Yes, there are several issues with the code. But I ask because I did try to fix the Perl script, only to discover that moving entire directories is not as easy as it sounds - `File::Copy::move` [is not guaranteed to work on directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628162/9300627), and I had additional trouble with `File::Copy::Recursive`. If the OP only wants to *delete* directories, that would make things much easier (so it's not such a minor detail).

Answer (score 8):

Simply with GNU **`find`** command (if supported):

```
find . -type f -mmin +30 -delete
```

---

As you've changed your condition, here's updated version:

```
find . -type f -cmin +15 -delete
```

Comment: Simple, if you have a `find` that supports all those fancy GNU options.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes, that's for GNU implementation (specifically)

Comment: I don't have GNU support.

Comment: When I was using solaris, I wanted to use the Gnu tool, so I downloaded them.

Comment: Also, the question says "older than 15 min of creation" (pre-edit "older than 30 min of creation"), not modified time (`-mmin`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to HP-UX, but on Solaris or any BSD system (i.e. not using GNU `find`), the following would work:

```
find . -type f -cmin +15 -print -exec rm {} +
```

This would find all regular files in or below the current directory, whose last inode status change was more than 15 minutes ago.  The pathnames of these files will be displayed and then the files would be deleted.

To be able to give interactive confirmation before deleting anything, use

```
find . -type f -cmin +15 -print -ok rm {} ';'
```

---

Most Unix file systems do not keep track of file *creation* time.  The `-cmin` predicate of `find` will test against the *ctime* of the file, i.e. the "change time" of the inode.  If the file's inode has not changed since it was created, then this would be its "creation time". The *ctime* timestamp gets updated on file creation and on modifications of ownership or permissions. Modification of the contents of the file also updates this timestamp.